# Wordpress - echo implode

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, implode, taxonomy-terms

I've got the following snippet to grab all the terms of the taxonomy available for the post.

```
$tags = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'books' );

if( $tags ) : ?>

<div class="listing-tag-list">

    <?php foreach( $tags as $tag ) :

        $tag_link = esc_url( get_term_link( $tag ) );

        $tag_output = '';
        $tag_output .= '<a href="' . $tag_link . '" class="listing-tag">';

        $tag_output .= '<span class="tag__text">' . $tag->name . '</span></a>';

        echo $tag_output;

        endforeach; ?>

 </div>

 <?php endif;
```

My problem is that currently, the terms show in a row without a space.

How can I separate them with a space and a comma?

I've been trying to use `implode` and so replace the `echo $tag_output;` with `echo implode( ', ', $tag_output );`, but I can't seem to be able to fit it into the current code.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why not add it directly in your loop

```
    $tag_output = '';
    $tag_output .= '<a href="' . $tag_link . '" class="listing-tag">';

    $tag_output .= '<span class="tag__text">' . $tag->name . '</span></a>';

    $tag_output .=", ";
    echo $tag_output;
```

And outside the loop,remove the last comma

```
    rtrim($tag_output,', ');
```

Comment: where exactly is the 'outside the loop'? Where exactly should the `rtrim($tag_output,', ');` sit? Would you be able to add it to your answer as a complete code?

Answer (score 0):

Easy and simple solution:

```
<?php echo get_the_terms_list( $post_id, 'books', '<div class="listing-tag-list">', ', ', '</div>' );?>
```

More details on [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list)

Or this one:

```
<?php

$tags = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'books' );
if( ! is_wp_error( $tags ) ){
    $links = array();

    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        $link = get_term_link( $tag, $tag );
        $links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="tag" class="listing-tag"><span class="tag__text">' . $tag->name . '</span></a>';
    }

    $before = '<div class="listing-tag-list">';
    $sep = ', ';
    $after = '</div>';
    echo $before . join( $sep, $tag_links ) . $after;
}
```